# deep linking mobile website view icon to open in facebook app?

Tags: facebook, web, deep-linking, social-media

I have a website that has social icons and is responsive for the mobile view. what I m trying to do is make the social icons (twitter, facebook...), when the web page is opened on mobiles or tablets, to open facebook app if available, if not to open in browser. and to open in browser when on desktop.

Thank you.